# How to tell whether or not Xcode is including a framework in a target

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two iOS apps that are identical except one is free with an ad. So I made another target for the paid version of the app. My question is how will I know that XCode is not including the AdMob framework in the paid version?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Link Binary with Libraries" section of the Build Phases of each target. Or, alternatively, click on the framework in the Project Navigator and look at the "Target Membership" section of the File Inspector to see which targets it is being included in.